# What went wrong with the nuclear boy scouts breeder reactor?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, radiation, gauss-law, nuclear-engineering

If I recall correctly the Nuclear boy scout tried to build a breeder reactor but the experiment gave him radiation poisoning because the neutron emitter was to emitting to many neutrons.

Does anyone know what exactly went wrong?
Did he not operate the moderator correctly?
Was he leaking to much flux?
Does anybody know?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hahn): “he never actually managed to build a reactor” “His homemade neutron source was often incorrectly referred to as a reactor, but it did end up emitting dangerous levels of radiation, likely well over 1,000 times normal background radiation.”

Comment: How does a neutron emitter emit dangerous levels of radiation without a reactor?

Comment: The danger depends on how much neutron-emitting material you have, how many neutrons per second are emitted by each gram of material, and what the energy of the emitted neutrons is. In general, the fewer neutrons doing cellular and genetic damage to your body, the better!

Comment: I believe his entire neighborhood was condemned as a nuclear disaster area (unless what I remember was just over exaggerated). That was all the result of some neutron emitting material?

Comment: “On June 26, 1995 the EPA, having designated Hahn's mother's property a Superfund hazardous materials cleanup site, dismantled the shed and its contents and buried them as low-level radioactive waste in Utah.” The Wikipedia article doesn’t say anything about the entire neighborhood, or about a “nuclear disaster”, so I think you have misremembered or heard an exaggeration of the facts.